# Liquibase ChangeSet not found when using rollback tag with changeSetId and changeSetAuthor

Tags: liquibase

I'm using Liquibase 3.4.2 (through Maven plugin). I have one **db.changelog-master.xml** file that include another two files: **db.changelog-2.6.xml** and **db.changelog-2.10**.

The **db.changelog-master.xml** looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<databaseChangeLog logicalFilePath="/database-migration/db.changelog-master.xml"
               xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">
    <include file="versions/db.changelog-2.6.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
    <include file="versions/db.changelog-2.10.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

In **db.changelog-2.10** I'm creating a `<changeSet>` to delete some data and, in the `<rollback>` tag I'm referencing the `<changeSet>` who created the same data. The two `<changeSet>` looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog logicalFilePath="/database-migration/versions/db.changelog-2.10.xml"
               xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
               xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">
    <changeSet id="1" author="my-user">
        <insert tableName="TABLE">
            <!-- SOME DATA -->
        </insert>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="2" author="my-user">
        <delete tableName="TABLE" />
        <rollback changeSetId="1" changeSetAuthor="my-user" />
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

The problem is, when I try to run the `update` command I ended up having the following error message:

> Change set /database-migration/versions/db.changelog-2.10.xml::1::my-user does not exist

Am I doing something wrong or this is a Liquibase bug?

Answer (score 0):

Please, check the matching of opening and closing XML-tags in `<changeSet id="1">`. In your example I see opening tag `<insert>` and closing tag `</update>`. Perhaps your problem was caused incorrect input data. It is very strange that XML-parser in liquibase doesn't detect this.

Try to replace closing tag `</update>` to more appropriate `</insert>`.

Answer (score -1):

add changeSetPath attribute

change_log_master:

`...
<include file="scripts/my_rollback_script.xml"/>
<include file="scripts/the_script_change_log.xml"/>
...`

the_script_change_log.xml :

`...
<rollback changeSetId="my_rollback_script_id" changeSetAuthor="me"
            changeSetPath="scripts/my_rollback_script.xml" />
...`